# Unity - 'Null object reference' error appears in Windows but not in macOS

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, .net-core

I am working with other developers in making a 2D game. I am the only one working with a macOS machine, while my other friends are working with Windows machines.

I made a recursive function that extracts the underlying primitive fields and their data from an object.

It seems to cause an error when encountering passing an object that has an empty List<> object (a list with 0 items) as it deals with the _syncroot variable.

```
public List<KeyValuePair<FieldInfo, object>> FlattenAndGetPrimitiveFields(object o)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<FieldInfo, object>> l = new List<KeyValuePair<FieldInfo, object>>();
    foreach (FieldInfo f in o.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        if (!f.FieldType.IsPrimitive && f.FieldType != typeof(string) && f.FieldType.BaseType != typeof(System.Enum))
        {
            //Debug.Log(f);
            //Debug.Log(o);
            object nonPrimitiveField = f.GetValue(o);
            // Can use the AddRange method to make this faster.
            l = l.Concat(FlattenAndGetPrimitiveFields(nonPrimitiveField)).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            KeyValuePair<FieldInfo, object> p = new KeyValuePair<FieldInfo, object>(f,o);
            l.Add(p);
        }
    }
    return l;
}
```

I just want to get the underlying primitive fields - however, this code  **already works for my macOS machine and not my friends' Windows machines.**

They are running .NET Framework, while I have the Mono Framework and .NET Core installed.

Comment: .NET Core and .NET Framework are different. So first try to make your development infrastructure uniform.

Comment: In which line do you have this issue?

Comment: `l = l.Concat(...).ToList();` - side note, but that looks **really, really** inefficient; why not just `l.AddRange(...)` ? or refactor it to pass the list *in* when used recursively, and use `.Add` ?

Comment: *`I made a recursive function that extracts the underlying primitive fields and their data from an object.`* Why do you even need this?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the quick comments. After a week, my partner on the Windows machine fixed it by identifying the '[' character and removing it.

Also, this function is used for serializing objects into a CSV format.